# Isn't it a huge security issue to include the MAC address inside of an IPv6 address by default

Tags: security, ipv6, privacy

Many times you don't want to be identified while surfing. For one thing your browsing history might be sold without your knowledge, and with no benefit to you.

Comment: Related question on SuperUser: [How to avoid exposing my MAC address when using IPv6?](http://superuser.com/q/243669/1686)

Answer (score 27):

Whether or not it is a 'major concern' is a point of opinion, but this idea has been had before, and resulted in action. Microsoft itself proposed an RFC to cover just this. RFC [4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941), *Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6* (Sept, 2007). IIRC, Windows defaults to use this, the Linux IPv6 stack has this as an option (your distro-of-choice may already set it by default), and OS X 10.6 also has support. That's a very large portion of end-user devices right there.

Comment: On most systems, these privacy extension can be enabled by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/use_tempaddr` as root (for runtime configuration).

Comment: +1 The largest concern is tracking people as they move from one point to another and any valuable information you could extrapolate from that.

Comment: Does anybody here know how to enable it under OSX?

Comment: @Fubarro The link @grawity posted has that information.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is a concern, and it is the reason some operating systems intentionally do not use the EUI-64 standard, preferring to use random data for the last 64 bits of their address.

Comment: Not entirely random though. A few of the bits are used to indicate how the address was generated.